Pdfsandwich does not work
I use arch linux.
When running pdfsandwich, I get the following error:
ERROR: Command "OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 tesseract /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich76f2d2.tif>/dev/null 2>&1 /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich6ff0e9  -l eng pdf " failed. 
Terminating pdfsandwich. All temporary files are kept.

after receiving the error message
WARNING: The convert command is deprecated in IMv7, use "magick" instead of "convert" or "magick convert"

Does anyone know what the problem is? I do not know where to begin to try fixing it.
EDIT: When running
tesseract /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich76f2d2.tif /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich6ff0e9  -l eng pdf

I get
Error opening data file /usr/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.


That looks like this psdsandwitch thing is trying to run tesseract /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich76f2d2.tif>/dev/null 2>&1 /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich6ff0e9  -l eng pdf. Since it also claims that all temp files are kept, try running tesseract /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich76f2d2.tif /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich6ff0e9  -l eng pdf and see if you can get anything more informative.

@terdon: I ran it and updated the question.

On Debian /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata comes with tesseract-ocr-eng package..

OK, so the issue is with how tesseract was installed, presumably. I don't know the first thing about this, so I can't really help, but try to find the tesseract directory (probably in /etc or /usr/share) and then run the command setting the variable accordingly. So if you have /etc/tesseract, try with TESSDATA_PREFIX=/etc/tesseract tesseract /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich76f2d2.tif /tmp/pdfsandwich_tmpae6a1b/pdfsandwich6ff0e9  -l eng pdf.

OK, so the tessdata directory contains the following: afr.traineddata  configs  osd.traineddata  pdf.ttf  tessconfigs . In particular, there is no reference to the english language (the directories tessconfigs and configs neither).
